# What is the distribution of an unconditioned random variable knowing the conditional distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, conditional-probability

I have two random variables $X$ and $Y$. I know that $Y$ can be approximated by a $N(\mu_1,\sigma_1^2)$ distribution (in particular $Y$ is not negative) and I also know that $X|Y \sim N(a+bY,c+dY)$ for some constants $a,b,c,d$.

What can I infer about the distribution of $X$? Is there some simple formula I can derive?

My intuition tells me that it might also a normal distribution with $\mu_2 = a+b\mu_1$ but I can't tell what the variance will be.

I'm not sure that this will be the case though. If anyone knows of a closed form formula that would be of tremendous help.

Comment: I fail to understand "in particular Y is not negative". If Y is normal with nonzero variance then P[Y<0] is **never** zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The distribution of $X$ will be given by
\begin{align}
f(x)
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,y)dy\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x|y) f(y) dy\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-(x-a-by)^2/(c+dy)}}{\sqrt{2\pi(c+dy)}} \frac{e^{-(y-\mu_1)^2/\sigma_1^2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma_1} dy\\
\end{align}
The problem with the integral is that you have a mixed exponent ($2bxy$) in the first exponential that won't allow you to factor out a function of $x$ as a factor and have an integrand that is independent of $x$. To find an analytical expression for the integral looks infeasible to me. Maybe ask mathematica or something similar for that.

BTW: Are you sure about your conditional probability? With finite probability you have a negative variance for X!

Comment: Thanks a lot! So I cheated a little bit, the distribution of Y is not normal (and in particular it is not negative) but it follows a distribution which can be approximated by a normal distribution (I have not found a closed form formula for it and I doubt there is one so I tried to simplify it). Sorry I didn't clarify this in the initial question.

Comment: That's ok. I work with stochastic PDE in applied math and we cheat like that quite often... Gaussians are just so practical and you just hope that this little bit of cheating won't bite you in the back...