# Finding the unconditional distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, improper-integrals, conditional-probability

I found two similar questions. One has a good answer [What is the distribution of an unconditioned random variable knowing the conditional distribution?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/331193/what-is-the-distribution-of-an-unconditioned-random-variable-knowing-the-conditi) .

I have a similar problem that I think should be ***much*** simpler. We have:

> $ X \in U(0,1) $.
>
> $ Y|X=x \in U(0,x) $.

From this I know how to calculate $ E[Y]=1/4 $ and $ Var(Y) $ but I want to find the distribution of $ Y $.

$$
f_Y(y)= 
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{X,Y}(x,y) \,dx =
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_Y(y|x) f_X(x) \,dx 
$$

Now, $ f_X(x)=1 $ and $ f_Y(y|x)=1/x $. But I am completely lost at how to reason about the limits of integration here. Clearly the integral diverges unless I plug in something different, but what?

Or is this the wrong way to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I am completely lost at how to reason about the limits of integration here.

Yes, and this is because the densities are **not** what you write. Rather, $f_X$ and $f(\ \mid x)$ are defined on the whole real line $\mathbb R$ by
$$
f_X(x)=\mathbf 1_{0\lt x\lt 1},\qquad f(y\mid x)=\frac1x\cdot\mathbf 1_{0\lt y\lt x}.
$$
Note that $f_X(x)$ exists for every $x$ and that, if $x$ is in $(0,1)$, $f(y\mid x)$ exists for every $y$. One usually extends $f(\ \mid x)$ by $f(y\mid x)=0$ for every $y$ if $x$ is not in $(0,1)$. Then, as you explained, for every $y$,
$$
f_Y(y)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_Y(y\mid x)f_X(x)\mathrm dx,
$$
that is,
$$
f_Y(y)=\int_0^1\frac1x\mathbf 1_{0\lt y\lt x}\mathrm dx=\mathbf 1_{0\lt y\lt 1}\int_y^1\frac1x\mathrm dx=\text{____}\cdot\mathbf 1_{0\lt y\lt 1}.
$$

Comment: -ln(y). Still hard for me to realize to put the y in the lower limit. I would have put 0+ or something... Thank you.

Comment: The purpose of this whole indicator stuff is to make this precise step obvious because mechanical.

Comment: It does indeed make you think about it. Will try to incorporate it from here on out.